# Android import intent contents within another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

am trying to send a variable from one activity to another i have set up an intent to send to the second activity. what i want to know is in the second activity what do i need to do in order to be able to use that variable in an if statement?

heres my code

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(TheLeagueActivity.this,IntroActivity.class);

                                    mainIntent.putExtra("leagueCount", leagueCount);

                                    TheLeagueActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);

                                    TheLeagueActivity.this.finish();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `onCreate()` method of `IntroActivity` write the following code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    // -1 is default value if no value associated with key "leagueCount"

    int leagueCount = intent.getIntExtra("leagueCount", -1);

   /*
      if leagueCount is not equal to -1
      use leagueCount here

   */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

String strExtra = getIntent().getExtras().getString("leagueCount");

...that's it! ;)
(Depending on what dataType u put in, u have to use "getInt()" or sth..)

Answer (score 0):

In the target activty, call `getIntent` to retrieve the intent, then use `getStringExtra`, `getIntExtra`, etc. to retrieve the intent parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what is your variable.
It seems to be an int.
So you will call like this:

```
int myVar = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("leagueCount");

if (myVar == 2) {
    //do the stuff
}
```